# How can two photons with different frequencies created by parametric down conversion be indistinguishable?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, quantum-optics, identical-particles

We have two photons created by the same four wave mixing process. How are they indistinguishable if they have different wavelengths? I know that as they are created at the same moment by the same process, they are indeed entangled, but I cannot understand how they have different wavelengths and they are indistinguishable at the same time.

Comment: Can you give more context? Photons with different wavelengths are indeed not indistinguishable.

Comment: The photons are created with a four wave mixing process inside a kai3 crystal. I have read some papers about this and they all seem to inherently assume that photons created in such a process are entangled. I can attach a specific paper on this topic but all of the papers I read have one thing in common: that spontaneous parametric down conversion processes create entangled photons.

Comment: entanglement is different than indistinguishable.  If they have a different energy, their spins may be entangled indistinguishably, ( who has the +1 or -1, because of the probability inherent in quantum mechanics) but if they have different energy they are distinguishable as photons.

Comment: If the photons have different wavelengths then they cannot be called indistinguishable. The papers you refer to might be talking about *degenerate* FWM which does produce indistinguishable photons, at identical wavelengths - or they might be completely wrong. It's impossible to tell which of the two without more context or explicit examples of the papers that say this.

Comment: Also: four-wave mixing and spontaneous parametric down-conversion are completely different processes, at different orders of nonlinearity. The fact that you're conflating the two is indicative that there may be other crucial aspects of the papers that you might have missed - so, post explicit example references.

Comment: Recording https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-wave_mixing there are three photons getting converted into a fourth photon. How you get two photons created? Or what I missunderstood?

Comment: In a classical sense, to create f4, we need f3 as an input as well as f1 and f2 (in some cases f1 can be =f2 by the way). But from a quantum mechanical point of view even a vacuum input (assuming there is a single photon in every frequency - a certain noise), we can input only f1 and f2 and get f3 and f4 as the output. The first case, i.e. when we have a nonzero f3 input is called stimulated four wave mixing while the second one, i.e. zero f3 input, is called spontaneous FWM. As I understand, we need the spontaneous FWM to get entangled photons pairs with f3 and f4.

Answer (score -2):

> We have two photons created by the same four wave mixing process. ... they have different wavelengths.... I know that as they are created at the same moment by the same process, they are indeed entangled,...

In your case, it is obvious that the knowledge about the frequencies of each photon is unknown to an observer as long as the frequency of one of the photons is not measured. At that moment, the uncertainty (function) - which photon has which frequency - collapses. The result is unambiguous.

Another result of a well designed parametric down conversion are photons of the same wavelengths but entangled spin orientations. To prove the entanglement is more difficult because the spin orientation could be any value in the range of 360°. To measure the spin one use a filter which let photons in the range from say 0° - 90° and 180° - 270° through. So in 50% a photon with randomly orientation of his spin is blocked. To prove the entanglement one has to carry out the measurement on more than one photon pair and only after a lot of measurements the correlation occurs from which we conclude than about the strong entanglement.

> How can two photons with different frequencies created by parametric down conversion be indistinguishable?

They are indistinguishable as long as nothing is measured. After the measurement of one of the photon, the result for the second is known without measurement. BUT this is right only for a process (the parametric down conversion) for which the production of photons with two wavelengths is well designed. Because it could be that the process changes under temperature influences. So you will be sure about the entanglement only for a well designed setup.

The difference between the collapse of the uncertainty about the result for spin entanglement and for frequency entanglement is the next. The frequency entanglement is a binary system, the spin entanglement is a fifty-fifty process and only after many measurements with always the same setup of unchanged in their orientations filters a correlation occurs which gives the knowledge about the entanglement.

Your example is brilliant. It shows that the discussion about spooky action at distance (spukhafte Fernwirkung) could be terminated. Simply the particles are from the moment of creation in an unambiguously state and it is obvious that the measurement of one particle gives us the knowledge of the state of the second.

Comment: "The information is unknown to the observer" is *not* what "indistinguishable" means in QM - if the two photons are in orthogonal states, then nothing short of a deliberate quantum-eraser projective measurement onto a coherent superposition will render them indistinguishable. I can't tell whether this is negligent or deliberate misinformation, but (apart from a correct but irrelevant interlude in the second paragraph) it's completely wrong.